# Multiplying 2 Pandas Dataframes with different numbers of columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have 2 pandas dataframes with a different number of columns. df1 contains 40 rows x 23320 columns while df2 contains 40 rows x 1 column. All columns of df1 have to be multipyed by df2. But my result only contains either NaN values or an unchanged df1 (depending on what I am trying).
I don't get an error. This is python 2.7 and I have to use it.

Here is a picture of the 2 dataframes. [image]

I tried the following code:

```
hnklnTnk = df7.mul(lndf)
```

or

```
hnklnTnk = df7 * lndf
```

I suspect that maybe something could be wrong with the dfs, because if I try df7.round(2) it stays the same.

Answer (score 0):

```
df1.multiply(df2.values, axis=1)
```

or try:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(df1.values * df2.values, columns=df2.columns)
```

Comment: If I try this code I get the following: ValueError: Unable to coerce to DataFrame, shape must be (40, 23320): given (40L, 1L)

Comment: have you tried ton inverse df1 and df2 : df2.multiply(df1.values, axis=1)

Comment: Yes I have. Same Error.

Comment: @neihilrach What about without the `axis=1`?  `df7.mul(indf.values)`

Comment: tried that aswell. tried axis=0 too. Both didnt work. I still suspect that the decimals of the bigger df are causing troubles because I cant round them. The decimals of the smaller df I can round.

Comment: what is your version of pandas?

Comment: I was able to solve it like this: df8 = df7.mul([3.349026509, 2.368197256, 1.882689441, 1.55726704, 1.312144582, 1.115434288,
0.951131237, 0.810052638, 0.686438682, 0.576437787, 0.477346884, 0.387195787, 0.304504072,
0.228131093, 0.157179357, 0.090929971, 0.02879819, -0.029698016, -0.084960695, -0.137328681,
-0.18709019, -0.234492429, -0.279749021, -0.323045826, -0.364545557, -0.404391466, -0.44271033,
-0.479614887, -0.515205832, -0.549573476, -0.582799123, -0.614956235, -0.646111403, -0.676325181,
-0.705652796, -0.734144752, -0.761847355, -0.788803165, -0.815051391,-0.840628233], axis=0)

Comment: I couldnt use one df, which is annoying, but this works at least.

Answer (score 0):

I cannot find documentation on the latest version of pandas for python 2.7, but this should work if you have a transform function: `df2.transform(lambda x: x * df1.values)`.

full example for two DFs: one with many columns and the other with a single column. both have the same number of rows:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame([10,20,30,40,50,60,70,80,90,100])
df2 = pd.DataFrame({
    'col1': [.1,.20,.30,.40,.50,.60,.70,.80,.90,1],
    'col2': [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10],
    'col3': [10,20,30,40,50,60,70,80,90,100]
})

df2 = df2.transform(lambda x: x * df1.values)
```

documentation on `pd.DataFrame.transform`: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.transform.html

Comment: I tried to implement your code:  hnklnTnk = df7.transform(lambda x: x * lndf.values). But i got the following error: Exception: ('Data must be 1-dimensional', u'occurred at index 427005')

Comment: the "1-dimensional" error probably means lndf is not a one-column series of values. If so, maybe `df2.transform(lambda x: x * df1['name_of_column'].values)` will do the trick.

Comment: also: have you tried running my sample code to see if it works? never tried pandas on python 2.7, so there's always a change things dont match. I've tested that snippet myself on python 3.8.5 and I worked as expected

Comment: I was able to solve it like this: df8 = df7.mul([3.349026509, 2.368197256, 1.882689441, 1.55726704, 1.312144582, 1.115434288, 0.951131237, 0.810052638, 0.686438682, 0.576437787, 0.477346884, 0.387195787, 0.304504072, 0.228131093, 0.157179357, 0.090929971, 0.02879819, -0.029698016, -0.084960695, -0.137328681, -0.18709019, -0.234492429, -0.279749021, -0.323045826, -0.364545557, -0.404391466, -0.44271033, -0.479614887, -0.515205832, -0.549573476, -0.582799123, -0.614956235, -0.646111403, -0.676325181, -0.705652796, -0.734144752, -0.761847355, -0.788803165, -0.815051391,-0.840628233], axis=0)

Comment: I couldnt use the one dataframe, which is annoying, but this works at least.

Comment: This is suboptimal at best... you're not using df2 but hardcoded values, which is a recipe for bugs later on. Also, what would you do if you had 50k rows, instead of 40? It seems to me you are having a hard time extracting the values from df2 and passing it as a list, so I would recommend you taking a closer look on the `.loc` and `.iloc` methods in Pandas Documentation and learn how to extract a 1-dimensional array. You should be able to get the exact array without any hard coding and then pass it to the `mul` or `transform` method, both should do the job. Split and conquer, good luck.